# Under Mint 12 and the latest version of the Enlightenment window manager the battery monitor gadget doesn't report correctly

Tags: linux, linux-mint, battery, enlightenment

Can anyone give me a clue where to look to fix it, and, can anyone point me to a good replacement?

Comment: e17 being Enlightenment 0.17, or something else? Please don't use obscure abbreviations (and yes, Enlightenment counts as obscure nowadays).

Comment: @Gilles edited.